# Dynamic styling using tailwind

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to code a custom cursor and I want to set x and y position(obtained from mousepos) to top and left positions using tailwind- which is not working for some reason.

The  `top-[${mousepos.y}] ,left-[${mousepos.x}]` stylings aren't working, the others work fine.

The code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Practice = () => {
  const [mousepos, setMousepos] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  useEffect(() => {
    const mouseMove = (e) => {
      setMousepos({
        x: e.clientX,
        y: e.clientY,
      });
    };
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseMove);
    };
  }, []);
  console.log(mousepos);

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className={`fixed pointer-events-none rounded-full border-2 w-[50px] h-[50px] border-violet-600 top-[${mousepos.y}] left-[${mousepos.x}]`}
      ></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Practice;
```

Comment: This isn't how tailwind works. The classes are compiled so all those classes don't exist. You're better off using an inline style.

Comment: it does check this https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode

Comment: It doesn't seem like a very good performant idea to generate potentially thousands of classes constantly being added and removed from an element. Inline style would just be better.

Comment: I already did check the JIT thing and it confused me even more honestly. Up untill now I thought the problem was with my code, guess its a tailwind problem. Can you guys like comment the correct code(the JIT thing included) so that I can glance over it? The JIT info is going over my head and an example would be better.

Comment: Completely forget about using tailwind, this is not a good use-case for it. Just bind those variables to an inline style for top and left.  `style={{ left: '${x}px', top: '${y}px' }}`

Answer (score 1):

TailwindCSS doesn't allow you to generate classes dynamically. So when you use the following to generate the class…

`top-[${mousepos.y}] left-[${mousepos.x}]`

…TailwindCSS will not pick that up as a valid TailwindCSS class and therefore will not produce the necessary CSS.

Instead, you must include the full name of the class in your source code. You can return the full value like this

```
function  myFunc() {
  return `top-[${mousepos.y}] left-[${mousepos.x}]` ;
}
```

And use it like this way

```
className={`fixed pointer-events-none rounded-full border-2 w-[50px] h-[50px] border-violet-600 ${myFunc}`}
```

By doing it this way, the entire string for every class is in your source code, so TailwindCSS will know to generate the applicable CSS.

Read more: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#class-detection-in-depth